# Is there an event for listening to click on "Stop Sharing" button?

Tags: webrtc, screensharing

[Image URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS7ii.png)

I have used getDisplayMedia() API. And i want to run some code on stop-sharing button click.

Answer (score 5):

The "stop sharing" button will trigger 'ended' or 'inactive' event on the MediaStreamTracks. 
You can use the following code to listen,

```
mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', () => 
console.log('screensharing has ended'));
```

Check webRTC samples code for usage - https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/getdisplaymedia/js/main.js#L88